# how to make git repository folder like this

Tags: git, github

https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/tree/master/lib/vendor

It can jump to another repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). More information:

- https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial
- http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#submodules
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules
- http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html